# Getting all ID's matching a title in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, title

I am trying to pull out all post ID's that have the same post title. This is in a custom post type called 'course-manager'. Here is what I have so far:

```
    $pages = array();

    $args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'course-manager',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    query_posts( $args1 );
    $page = get_page_by_title( $current_post_title, 'OBJECT', 'course-manager' );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); //query all pages and get id's of pages with the specific title. Put id's in an array and use array in query below to query each id        
        $pages[] = $page->ID;
        echo $page->ID;

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

This should work in my opinion. I have four posts - two with the title I am searching for and 2 with a different title... however instead of getting the two differnt post ID's I want, I am getting 4 post ID's all the same. :/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `$args` array to this:

```
//Let's say you're searching the posts with the title 'The searched post':
$pages = array();
$args1 = array(
    's' => 'The searched post',
    'post_type' => 'course-manager',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
query_posts( $args1 );
```

Your `query_posts` will return all the posts with the title alike 'The searched post'.